# My question is whether given function is periodic or not

Tags: functions, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers, periodic-functions

F(x) =

- 1,  if x is rational
- 0, if x is irrational

So what i am really confused about is because all professors are telling me its periodic whose period is not defined, i mean it doesn't make any sense to me.
So they countered me by telling in constant function periodic i said yes but again they asked what is its period. I mean the problem is what is exact definition of periodic function they are not drawing the line.
So please help me with understanding it.

Comment: Didn't they give you a definition of "periodic function"? What was the exact definition?

Comment: I don't think its the defininition of periodic that's the issue, but the definiton of "the" period.  .i.e a specific *smallest* period.  It seems counter intuitive that there can be periodic functions that don't have a *smallest* period but constant functions and this function clearly are.

Answer (score 1):

The function is indeed periodic because $\mathbb{Q}$ is closed for the addition so for example $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, x \in \mathbb{Q} \iff x+1\in \mathbb{Q}$. This means that $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, F(x+1) = F(x)$.

We can conclude that $F$ is periodic and $1$ is *one* period.

Moreover, $\forall p\in\mathbb Q,\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, x \in \mathbb{Q} \iff x+p\in \mathbb{Q}$, which is enough to prove that: $$\forall p\in\mathbb Q,\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, F(x+p) = F(x)$$

Said differently any rational number is a period for $F$.

But we cannot give the *minimum period* because $\inf(\mathbb{Q_+}) = 0$.

That is the reason why F is periodic (we could exhibit its periods) but we cannot define **the** period (commonly the minimal positive period) because the inferior bound of the positive periods is $0$.

Comment: \inf is better than inf :)

Comment: @StéphaneJaouen: Merci Stéphane. I had never used `\inf` yet...

Comment: thank you so not having smallest period is not a problem for function being periodic. ok 

Answer (score 0):

The period of a function is the smallest positive $r$ so that $f(x+r) = f(x)$ for all $x$.

But some functions will have an infinite number of $r$s but none of them being a smallest positive $r$ so that $f(x+r) =f(x)$ for all $x$.

These functions are periodic because there do exist $r$ so that $f(x+r) = f(x)$ for all $x$.  But the do not have known periods because there is not *smallest* such (positive) number that do that.

In this case if $r\in \mathbb Q$ then $x+r\in \mathbb Q\iff x\in \mathbb Q$ and so $f(x+r) = f(x)$.  But there is no *smallest* positive $r$ that does this.  So $f$ is periodic without a defined specific period.

====

Note the restriction is that $r \ne 0$.  Obviously all functions have $f(x+0) = f(x)$ and obviously that doesn't count.